# Values do not get assigned properly via scanf

Tags: c, function, variables, scanf

I wrote a function in c which is supposed to scan for four values and assign those to four variables:

```
double xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax;

double set(double xmin, double xmax, double ymin, double ymax){

printf("\nxmin:\t");
scanf(" %lf",&xmin);
printf("\nxmax:\t");
scanf(" %lf",&xmax);
printf("\nymin:\t");
scanf(" %lf",&ymin);
printf("\nymax:\t");
scanf(" %lf",&ymax);
printf("\n");

return xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax;}
```

Somehow the values are lost when I use the function later in the main-function. I checked with the debugger and found that the values don't even get assigned in the first place. So the problem has to be in this function.

Comment: `return xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax;` This doesn't mean what you think it does. Go through the first chapters of your favorite tutorial again.

Comment: `return xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax;` returns the last value in the list

Comment: 1. Read the manual page and check the return values from `scanf`. 2. Read about the [comma operator](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi6g7zUi8LRAhUJIcAKHQ2pAzkQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FComma_operator&usg=AFQjCNE7qisSUg7u5BXhku7QzDf05p_8CQ&sig2=Mvuz2MycSJu0i4YNNWXuVg)

Comment: @GoodDeeds    set(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `set` initializes its own argument variables and returns the last one. It leaves the global variables of the name name untouched.  Removing the argument variables fixes the problem:

```
double xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;

void set(void) {
    printf("\nxmin:\t");
    scanf(" %lf", &xmin);
    printf("\nxmax:\t");
    scanf(" %lf", &xmax);
    printf("\nymin:\t");
    scanf(" %lf", &ymin);
    printf("\nymax:\t");
    scanf(" %lf", &ymax);
    printf("\n");
}
```

But a better approach is to pass the addresses of the variables, which can be made local to `main`, and to check the return value of `scanf()` for proper conversion:

```
int set(double *xmin, double *xmax, double *ymin, double *ymax) {
    printf("\nxmin:\t");
    if (scanf("%lf", xmin) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("\nxmax:\t");
    if (scanf("%lf", xmax) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("\nymin:\t");
    if (scanf("%lf", ymin) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("\nymax:\t");
    if (scanf("%lf", ymax) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Call from `main()` this way:

```
int main(void) {
    double xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;

    if (set(&xmin, &xmax, &ymin, &ymax)) {
        /* initialization error */
        exit(1);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to check the return value from `scanf`. Also is it a good idea to kind of recommend using global variables?

Comment: Are you sure that returning true (1) is best in the event of an error?

Comment: Perhaps an explanation why global variables are not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

Pass pointers to your values rather than the values; the `return`-statement becomes obsolete; Note that in `scanf` the `&` sign is removed as you have already a pointer to the value.

```
void (double *xmin, double *xmax, double *ymin, double *ymax) {
  printf("\nxmin:\t");
  scanf(" %lf",xmin);
  printf("\nxmax:\t");
  scanf(" %lf",xmax);
  printf("\nymin:\t");
  scanf(" %lf",ymin);
  printf("\nymax:\t");
  scanf(" %lf",ymax);
  printf("\n");
}
```

In function main, don`t forget to pass references:

```
int main {
  double xmin=0.0,xmax=0.0,ymin=0.0,ymax=0.0;
  set(&xmin, &xmax, &ymin, &ymax);
  ...
```

Comment: change the prototype to `void (double *xmin, double *xmax, double *ymin, double *ymax)` and remove the addressof operator `&` from the `scanf()` arguments.